# Why is the Lagrange polynomial the polynomial of least degree that fits n points

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I understand that it has degree at most n-1 for fitting n points. But I'm not sure I see the proof for why it is a polynomial of least degree that does the job?

Comment: What is your definition of "Lagrange polynomial"?

Comment: As stated, this is untrue. For instance, the polynomial $X$ of degree $1$ fits the three points $(-1,-1)$, $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: For an arbitrary set of n points, degree n-1 is the highest needed.  As others have noted, it could be less in special cases.

Comment: I was just reading wikipedia and they claim that the Lagrange polynomial is the polynomial of lowest degree that assumes the n data points, so I thought that if we do have a case where three points lines on a line, then the expansion of the lagrange polynomial would be of degree 1 polynomial (certain terms would cancel) is that not the case?

Comment: I realized this was a silly question, I forgot the fact that the polynomial with degree less than $n$ that passes through n points exists and is unique, clearly any other polynomial must have higher degree than $n$, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two points , there is a unique polynomial of first degree which passes through the points and it is a linear function which is a polynomial of first degree.

Now if you have three points, a polynomial of first degree does not necessarily fit the points so you have to go to polynomials of degree $2$ to find the right polynomial.

Now if you have $n$ points you can solve a system of n equations with $n$ unknowns to find the coefficients of the polynomial of   degree $n-1$,  $$ y= a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 +...+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}.$$

This polynomial is unique and the Lagrange Polynomial is simply a very smart way to write the equation of this polynomial without solving a system.

Comment: I realized this was a silly question, I forgot the fact that the polynomial with degree less than $n$ that passes through n points exists and is unique, clearly any other polynomial must have higher degree than $n$, thanks